Network problems OOTB Ubuntu 24.04
is anyone else experiencing network problems when trying to install Ubuntu 24.04?
I've worked with Ubuntu in the past on an old Dell computer. My daily runs Windows and I wanted to switch over to Linux. Despite having dabbled around in the past, I am quite new to Linux. Therefore, I wanted to start with an accessible distro.
I've created a bootable usb of Ubuntu 24.04 (official website) with Rufus and tried to install, according to the official install guide. However, during install there was no network detected, even though it is wired. I figured I might be able to figure out how to fix that later on, so I skipped that part during installation. After some crashes during the install process, I finally managed to get it working. However, still no internet and after looking through various online resources, I am still not able to fix those network problems.
I am on a Macbook M1 as well and the internet connection is fine as is the cable. Anyone has any ideas for a new Linux user?

Welcome to AskUbuntu. It seems like you are asking how to troubleshoot your wired ethernet connection. If so, please edit your question to clearly say that.

Also test that your ethernet cable is good. "it worked yesterday" is not a valid test -- they go bad unexpectedly.

Run sudo lshw. Scroll though the output to locate the hardware details of your wired ethernet adapter. Post a link to a clear, readable photo of that section to your question above.

Not sure if I'm hijacking this thread or should start a new one? I think I'm having a similar issue. Intel i Mac 27" A1312 circa 2011. 8Gb ram, Intel® Core™ i5-2400 × 4 core. 500Gb Crucial MX500 SSD . Installed 24.04 today. Install went perfect with WiFi connected, no errors.
Everything is working great, Bluetooth, WiFi, except ethernet. Even the video card seems to working, it'll play 1440P YouTube videos smoothly. I'm staggered how slick Ubuntu runs on this old hardware.
I don't see the normal wired ethernet icon when I plug in a cable. I tried a USB to LAN adapter and that shows up fine (wired icon appears) and works. I tried another known good cable, no change. Being USB 2 its a bit slow compared to my gigabit wired internet. Wifi is about as fast, 200Mb/s.
From sudo lshw I get:
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: enp2s0
version: 10
serial: c8:2a:14:1e:61:5d
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=6.8.0-31-generic firmware=57765-v1.37 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
resources: irq:16 memory:a8400000-a840ffff memory:a8410000-a841ffff
This computer is new to me. 22.04 was the same when I installed it a few days ago, no ethernet. Ive never had it running on iOS, previous owner sent it to Service Plus (an official Apple repairer in NZ). They cloned and then swapped the drive to the SSD and couldn't get iOS to boot. It wouldn't restore from internet recovery for me and I tried in vain to make a bootable iOS USB in windows with Transmac. So maybe it's just broken? The apple hardware test said everything was working but who knows if that is accurate. Ubuntu is my last attempt to keep this old thing in use. It's such a pretty piece of hardware.
I'm wondering if I'm missing a driver? I've done many Ubuntu installs and never had an issue with ethernet connectivity, but this is my first Apple computer.
Any ideas?

I ended up installing 22.04 and that worked smoothly, still don’t know why there were problems on 24.04
